# Removing question mark from query string with apache and htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I have a PHP page with querystring:

```
http://project.dev/?a=b&c=d
```

As you know, I can access the querystring with `$_GET` superglobal array:

```
print_r($_GET);
/*
Array
(
    [a] => b
    [c] => d
)
*/
```

I want to remove questionmark from querystring with Apache and `htaccess`, so when a user see my website with this address:

```
http://project.dev/a=b&c=d
```

It will be identical to this address:

```
http://project.dev/?a=b&c=d
```

and I can access the querystring as before: with `$_GET` superglobal array.

**Some Important Notes:**

1. I don't want to redirect user from URL **without** question mark to the URL **with** question mark.
2. I have both `GET` and `POST` requests to this page.
3. The querystring can **have** questionmark `?` itself, for example:
   `http://project.dev/?a=b&c=d?x=y`.
4. I want the addresses with question mark, automatically **redirect** to the one without question mark. For example when a user come to my site with this address:
   `http://project.dev/?a=b&c=d`
   I want to redirect user to this address:
   `http://project.dev/a=b&c=d`.
5. My website has only one page: `index.php`. Without any subfolders.

How can I do this in `htaccess`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have both GET and POST requests to this page.

This may be an issue, since the request body doesn't get included after a redirect. So if you've POSTed a request that has GET style params in the query string, the redirect will lose the POST params.

The rules you want will probably look something like this:

```
# Redirects query string to non-query string

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(GET|HEAD)\ /\?([^\ ]+)
RewriteRule ^ /%2? [L,R,NE]

# And back

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} .=.
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ /?$1 [L]
```

If you want a 301 redirect, replace the `R` flag in the first rule with `R=301`. The `NE` flag is needed s othat any encoded `?` in the query string shows up as `%3F` instead of the `%` getting encoded itself. You can alternatively try replacing `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} .=.` with `-f` and `-d` checks:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Unfortunately, It didn't work. I am running at `Apache/2.4.3 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.1c PHP/5.4.7`.

Comment: @Mojtaba "*it didn't work*" doesn't tell me very much, if that's all there is to say then I can't help you any further. These rules work [perfectly fine for me on a brand new Apache install in a blank htaccess file in the document root](http://i.stack.imgur.com/MIcHl.png)

Comment: I'm sorry Jon Lin. I am running PHP on windows with XAMPP, I created a folder called `querystring` in my htdocs and put there two files: `.htaccess` and `index.php`. In `.htaccess` I wrote your code, and when I go to this address `http://localhost/querystring/?a` my page works correctly and show querystring. But when I want to access the page without question mark, `http://localhost/querystring/a`, It gives me Error 404. It wants to go to a folder called `a`. And I tested my `.htaccess`. I wrote some illegal code on it, and my page gets Error 500. I'm here for giving you more info :).

Comment: @Mojtaba Your example has the request go to the document root, if your requests all go to another directory (like `querystring`) then these rules won't work because everything is written specifically for the document root. These rules are **not portable**. They need to be in the document root. If you want your `index.php` in a directory called `querystring`, then you need to replace in the first condition `^(GET|HEAD)\ /\?` to `^(GET|HEAD)\ /querystring/\?` and the rule `/%2?` to `/querystring/%2?`.

Comment: I move my files to the document root. But it failed. I still get Error 404. Can this be related to my Apache version?

Comment: @Mojtaba It's not your apache version. If you'll notice that I mention replacing the condition that checks for an **equal sign in the query string** with the bottom 2 conditions if you don't have equal signs (which you don't in the example in your previous comment)